# If $n, r, s$ are numbers and $P, R, S$ the product, of the divisors of $N, L, M$ respectively, where $N=LM$ and and are prime to one another......?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

**If $n, r, s$ are numbers and $P, R, S$ the products, of the divisors of $N, L, M$ respectively, where $N=LM$, and $L$ and $M$ are prime to one another prove that:—**

1)$n=rs$

2$P=R^sS^r$

First of all I think so the question is poorly defined because product of divisors of $N, L, M$ should be equals to $N, L, M$. So I am assuming $P, R, S$ the products of pairs of factors of $N, L, M$.

Here's what I have tried:—

> Let
>
> $L = a ^ { l } b ^ { m } c ^ { n } \dots$
>
> $M = x ^ { p } y ^ { q } z ^ { t } \dots$
>
> $LM = (a ^ { l } b ^ { m } c ^ { n } \dots) (x ^ { p } y ^ { q } z ^ { t } \dots)$
>
> Number of terms in $L=(l+1)(m+1)(n+1)\dots=r$
>
> Number of terms in $M=(p+1)(q+1)(t+1)\dots=s$
>
> Number of terms in $LM=N=[(l+1)(m+1)(n+1)\dots][(p+1)(q+1)(t+1)\dots]=n=rs$

I'm having trouble proving the second statement.

I know that the number of ways in which $N$ can be expressed as the product of two factors including $N$ and $1$, is $\frac{(n+1)}{2}$ or $\frac{n}{2}$  according as $N$ is or is not a perfect square.

But applying this gives me 2 cases for $N$ perfect square or not, similarly 4 cases for $L$ perfect square or not and $M$ perfect square or not. Considering all of them in one equation gives me even more cases.

**How can I solve this, Is there a better way to prove this?**

*Any help would be highly appreciated.*

Comment: As every number except 0 will divide a number z, the product of numbers dividing z is an infinite product which, as complex as it may be, can be handled by using the injection between x and 1/x (except for x = 1) to obtain 1.

Comment: @WilliamElliot This question is from Bernard and Child number theory Chapter 1 Q24. The authors didn't state anything about injection in the book. And that all the numbers must be integers (Even though it is not stated in the question).